# C# Upload base64 image to Cloudflare

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, base64, cloudflare

I made an Angular website where I can upload an image. I want to send the image to a .Net Rest Api.
I've been trying to upload the base64 image to cloudflare R2 in my .Net api with the S3 api.

This is the code that I have:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    public class FileController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static IAmazonS3 s3Client;
        
        public FileController()
        {
            string accesKey = <<accesKey>>;
            string secretKey = <<secretKey>>
            BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accesKey, secretKey);

            s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, new AmazonS3Config {
                ServiceURL = <<serviceURL>>,
            }) ;
        }

        [HttpPost("{fileName}")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public string uploadFile(string fileName, base64ImageDTO base64Image)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Image.base64String);

                using (s3Client)
                {
                    var request = new PutObjectRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = <<bucketName>>,
                        CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
                        Key = fileName,
                    };
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                    {
                        request.InputStream = ms;
                        var response = s3Client.PutObjectAsync(request);
                    }
                }
            } catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("aws fail");
            }

            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

The error that I get is the following:

```
Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: STREAMING-AWS4-HMAC-SHA256-PAYLOAD not implemented
 ---> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException: Exception of type 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException' was thrown.
   at Amazon.Runtime.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RedirectHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ResponseHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
```

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try awaiting the PutObjectAsync:

```
public Task<string> uploadFile(string fileName, base64ImageDTO base64Image)
{
    ...
    ...
    var response = await s3Client.PutObjectAsync(request);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Tnx for your comment, I have tried it, but it does not work either.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help. If I were you, I would put breakpoints in the code and use the debugger to step through the code. I'd have a look at what the response is, what the `base64Image`, etc. It could be that the `response` has important info you're missing. If you find anything helpful, include it in the question.